# Performing bulk inserts using REST API in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, rest, bulk

Is it possible to perform bulk insert through REST API in MongoDB? I cannot find any examples of that, only using the shell.

Comment: When you say "REST API" do you mean the built in REST API that comes with mongod or do you mean writing your own?

Comment: To which the elaborated comment would be that if you mean the built in REST API then such things are not supported, and not likely to be supported in other basic implementations. However it is of course possible to "write your own", where you send a "batch" of documents for insert/update/remove and apply the bulk operations API in your code. You could even implement a "commit" to execute a "batch" built from multiple requests, just as something like "solr" allows you do do.

Comment: Yes, I meant the built in REST API. Thank you for the answer.